# somewhat complex dev domain https on local network cert problems

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, openssl, mobile, firefox

I was trying to mirror my setup to prod as much as possible so I only serve my dev site over https. The setup goes like this...

1. I have a trusted CA on my machine made by [devcert](https://github.com/davewasmer/devcert)
2. I generated some certs and mounted them in a docker container and serve them on my site, I've added a .dev domain to the /etc/hosts in both the container, my local machine, and my mobile device, all of them get directed to the proper location when I point my browser to the .dev domain

Problems:

1. My android mobile device does not trust the certificate. I can't seem to use the chome [thisisunsafe](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/82rnr6/chrome_65_replaces_the_badidea_bypass_keyword/) hack because I cannot get a keyboard on the warning screen on mobile...

I've tried adding the CA as a trusted certificate on my phone via settings > secutiry > install from SD card but chrome still fails

2. Firefox (on my local dev machine) doesn't accept the certificate and fails with SEC_ERROR_BAD_SIGNATURE even though chrome works

I badly need to do some mobile debugging so I need to get this in a working condition ASAP, any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: I recommend to not use \*.dev domains. .dev is owned by Google and browsers have HSTS preloaded for this domain so you will never be able to add an explicit exception. Use a domain  which is not owned (and policed) by a third party instead.

Comment: right, good catch. That was not related to the problem, but I didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going back through the whole process and manually deleting my custom root CA from firefox and clearing the cache. After that everything seemed to be ok